# Collapsible top tab navigator when scrolling

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I want to implement a collapsible top tab navigator when scrolling using react navigation as is found on WhatsApp, Twitter and other apps. Nothing in the react navigation documentation directly specifies this. How do I go about this please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wix navigation has this feature. https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/#/
Specifically this option:

```js
topBar: {
  hideOnScroll: true
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Ziyo, am taking a look at it now

Comment: Hey @Ziyo, any idea how to move the page up to replace the hidden topBar?

Comment: If this is what you mean, you can follow their source code https://twitter.com/notbrent/status/1129689750137397248